# How to embed excel sheet to web page for editing and uploading it into database

Tags: javascript, angularjs

--> I'm getting iframe code to embed in microsoft excel. But I can see the sheet only in the web page.

--> I want to edit the embedded sheet and I want to add a button to upload that embedded sheet into test link database.
Can anyone please help me? Is there any plugin to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Method 1. You can create a google spreadsheet and there is an option to publish it to web and get the embed code for iframe. The iframe code can now be used in any webpage. The sheet will get displayed in the webpage but you wont be able to edit the cells.

Method 2. You can create a google spreadsheet. You can directly use the spreadsheet url (eg: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jTvLJsqOVOnmCrNCCqoUs9vRJkYrD_kJRLyY/edit#gid=0) which you see in your browser's address bar and use it as the src to iframe in your webpage. The spreadsheet will get displayed in your webpage and you can also edit the cells in it. Thanks to the **x-frame-options header** which google has not applied/checked.

Sync Data between Sheet and DB:

1. You can write a macro code/ Google Script function which will get triggered/ executed on various events such as sheet open, row edited, button clicked etc. In the code you can create a JDBC connection to your database such as MYSQL, MSSQL, Mongo etc and sync the rows as per your logic. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/
2. You can also use plugins such as Zapier, Kloud.io etc to sync the data (Bidirectional) between the sheet and your preferred DB.

Comment: Is there any option other than google spreadsheet? because we don't have access to google docs. @Rahul Malu